# Return sum of even numbers in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, ecmascript-6

The solution I am looking for: My function needs to return the sum of all the even numbers in my array. The expected answer is 30.

The problem I am having: The answer it is returning is 25.

```js
let numStr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

const sumEvens = (numStr) => {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < numStr.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0){ 
    sum = sum + numStr[i];
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
 
console.log(sumEvens(numStr));
```

I changed the function to push to a sum array and returned the sum array  to find the reason it is returning 25 is because it is making an array of odd numbers instead of the even.

```js
let numStr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

const sumEvens = (numStr) => {
  let sum = [ ];
  for (let i = 0; i < numStr.length; i++) {
    if (i % 2 === 0){ 
    sum.push(numStr[i]);
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
 
console.log(sumEvens(numStr));
```

The only way I am able to get the correct output of 30 is to make my if statement `if (i % 2 !== 0)`, but I know that means to only add if the number in the array is NOT even.

I feel like I am so close, but missing one minor thing. The other SO posts and MDN did not help me.

Comment: Do you mean to sum even numbers or numbers with even *index*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

```
if (i % 2 === 0){
```

You're checking whether the *index* being iterated over is even. So, you'll end up adding together `numStr[0]`, `numStr[2]`, etc. Check the value at that index instead:

```
if (numStr[i] % 2 === 0) {
```

```js
let numStr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

const sumEvens = (numStr) => {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < numStr.length; i++) {
    if (numStr[i] % 2 === 0) {
    sum = sum + numStr[i];
    }
  }
  return sum;
}
 
console.log(sumEvens(numStr));
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `filter` with `reduce` instead:

```js
let numStr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

const sumEvens = arr => arr.filter(e => !(e % 2)).reduce((a, b) => a + b);

console.log(sumEvens(numStr));
```

The issue with your current code is you were checking the index, not the element.

Comment: To it's clear the OP is a beginner and has been assigned a homework task. For how your answer is the most "pretty" (coding wise), I don't believe it is the most useful in this specific case; it might seem too abstract.
A simpler explanation and a solution similar to the way the OP sees the problem might be more helpful, perchance.

Comment: For me it's the good answers, the most elegant and modern. The answers above is explaining by the code when, effectivly, this one has no explaination about filter and reduce. However it's also a good training to see native prototype in action.

Comment: This is still very useful to see the many ways to get the same answers. Methods are great, but still important to see what the methods are doing behind the scenes to get a full understanding. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 2):

Use filter and reduce.

```js
let numStr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

let sum = numStr.filter(i => i%2 ===0).reduce((a,v) => a += v);

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JavaScript reduce

```js
let numStr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

function getSum(total, num) {
  return total + (num%2===0?num:0);
}
var my_sum = numStr.reduce(getSum, 0);

console.log(my_sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Already there are many good solutions listed here. However, I thought of sharing the following using `for...of` loop:

```
const nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

const sumEvens = (nums) => {
  var total = 0;
  for (let i of nums) { 
    if (i%2 ===0) total += i; 
  }
  return total;
}
```

Also noticed many of the solutions involving filter & reduce failed to give a **default value** for the reduce. This will end up in an error if you pass in an empty array. It could be better handled this way:

```
const sum = nums.filter(a => a%2 === 0).reduce((a, b) => a+b, 0);
```

In a totally different situation, if you know you always need to perform this summation for a range of even. numbers. We can also do it this way:

```
const sumEvensInRange = (from , to) => {
  if (from % 2 !== 0 || to % 2 !== 0) {
    console.log(`even numbers expected: [${from}, ${to}]`);
    return -1;
  }
  if (from > to || from === to) {
    console.log(`invalid input: {to} should be greater than ${from}`);
    return -1;
  }
  return (from + to) * (1 + (to - from)/2) / 2;
}

console.log(sumEvensInRange(10, 20)); // 90
```

In such a scenario the above will give the best performance in terms of `Big O notation`. Here we are using a formula instead of any kind of loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
let evenNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
let sum = 0;
for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
{
  if (i % 2 === 0)
  {
    sum = sum + i;
  }
}

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Do not post an answer with merely codes. While your solution can be useful, you should also explain why the code will fix the problem that was described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];

const sumOfEven = (a) => {

  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] % 2 === 0) {
      sum = sum + a[i];
    }
  }
  return sum;

}
console.log(sumOfEven(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution using forEach method :

let data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,6,8,10];

```
    function evenSum(array){
        let sum = 0; //intiating sum with zero for adding it to first even element that will make sum equal to that element

        array.forEach(element => {
            if ((element % 2)==0){ //checking if element of array is even or not
                sum = element + sum; // if it is then we can add that element to previous sum
            }
        });
        return sum
    }
    console.log(evenSum(data));
```